# Single SQL to get multiple counts with different where clauses, is this possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, where-clause

I have a table as below,

```
+-----+--------+-----------+----------+
| id  | type_id| product_id| date     |
+-----+--------+-----------+----------+
|  1  |   1    |   300     |22/01/2013|
|  2  |   1    |   800     |22/01/2013|
|  3  |   1    |   400     |30/01/2013|
|  4  |   1    |   300     |05/02/2013|
|  5  |   5    |   300     |27/02/2013|
|  6  |   1    |   300     |28/02/2013|
|  7  |   3    |   400     |12/03/2013|
|  8  |   5    |   400     |02/03/2013|
|  9  |   1    |   300     |06/03/2013|
| 10  |   1    |   400     |06/03/2013|
| 11  |   5    |   400     |06/03/2013|
| 12  |   1    |   400     |08/03/2013|
```

Lets say if I want to get count of each type for each product group by month and year, Is this possible? Output that I'm after should be something similar to following..

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+------+------+
|product_id |count_type_1|count_type_3 |count_tyep_5| month| year |
+-----------+------------+-------------+------------+------+------+
| 300       |     1      |      0      |     0      |   01 | 2013 |
| 800       |     1      |      0      |     0      |   01 | 2013 |
| 400       |     1      |      0      |     0      |   01 | 2013 |
| 300       |     2      |      0      |     1      |   02 | 2013 |
| 300       |     1      |      0      |     0      |   03 | 2013 |
| 400       |     2      |      1      |     2      |   03 | 2013 |
```

Is this can be achieve using a single SQL?

PS: This is on a MYSQL server

Comment: Will you have a certain number of types or is that dynamic?

Comment: Shouldn't Product ID's be unique? Using both a Product ID and Type ID will cause frustration.

Comment: Product id is unique, but there are more than 50k products

Comment: I believe you can do this by using the CASE statement, this is frequently called 'conditional counting with case'. Check out this excellent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8832505/614880

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following to *pivot* the data which uses an aggregate function and a `CASE` expression to create each column:

```
select 
  product_id,
  sum(case when type_id=1 then 1 else 0 end) count_type_1,
  sum(case when type_id=2 then 1 else 0 end) count_type_2,
  sum(case when type_id=3 then 1 else 0 end) count_type_3,
  sum(case when type_id=4 then 1 else 0 end) count_type_4,
  sum(case when type_id=5 then 1 else 0 end) count_type_5,
  month(date) month,
  year(date) year
from yourtable
group by product_id, month(date), year(date)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2151d/1)

This gives the result:

```
| PRODUCT_ID | COUNT_TYPE_1 | COUNT_TYPE_2 | COUNT_TYPE_3 | COUNT_TYPE_4 | COUNT_TYPE_5 | MONTH | YEAR |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        300 |            1 |            0 |            0 |            0 |            0 |     1 | 2013 |
|        300 |            2 |            0 |            0 |            0 |            1 |     2 | 2013 |
|        300 |            1 |            0 |            0 |            0 |            0 |     3 | 2013 |
|        400 |            1 |            0 |            0 |            0 |            0 |     1 | 2013 |
|        400 |            2 |            0 |            1 |            0 |            2 |     3 | 2013 |
|        800 |            1 |            0 |            0 |            0 |            0 |     1 | 2013 |
```

Comment: Both the answers are correct and thanx a lot, I had accept fthiella's answer since fthiella answered first (like 1 mins before :D) but I up voted your answer..

Comment: @Thanu actually I answered first by about 15 seconds. If you hover over the answered time, you will see that actual time an answer was posted

Comment: @thanu yes, I actually answered 10 seconds later...

Comment: @fthiella Oh ..yes I can see that.. as my own policy I have to accept bluefeet's answer sorry about that. Anyway I have up voted yours and Thank you very much for your answer....

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT
  product_id,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN type_id=1 THEN 1 END) count_type_1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN type_id=2 THEN 1 END) count_type_2,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN type_id=3 THEN 1 END) count_type_3,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN type_id=4 THEN 1 END) count_type_4,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN type_id=5 THEN 1 END) count_type_5,
  MONTH(date) month,
  YEAR(date) year
FROM
  products
GROUP BY
  product_id,
  MONTH(date),
  YEAR(date)
```

Comment: ya its not the same column